# How can I improve this price calculation code doing 4 calculations now, but more coming in the near future?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to work out how to improve a bit of code I wrote that uses a few rules to calculate a few different pricings for car insurance. Here's the piece that bothers me:

```
public Insurance GetInsurance(CarData carData)
{
    var insurance = new Insurance();

    insurance.priceGeneral = this.CalculatePrice(new Car { BrandDealer = false, MonthPayment = false, CarData = carData });
    insurance.priceGeneralMonth = this.CalculatePrice(new Car { BrandDealer = false, MonthPayment = true, CarData = carData });
    insurance.priceBrandDealer = this.CalculatePrice(new Car { BrandDealer = true, MonthPayment = false, CarData = carData });
    insurance.priceBrandDealerMonth = this.CalculatePrice(new Car { BrandDealer = true, MonthPayment = true, CarData = carData });

    return insurance;
}
```

Note that there is a significant difference in calculating monthly payments over the normal price (yearly payment), and the dependind on whether BrandDealer is true or false there is also a different calculation for it. I tried to eliminate this variable, but the customer demands these rules.

I'm aware that some of the properties are not actual properties of a "Car", but I will be refactoring that soon as well.

I am bothered by the fact that I am doing this calculation 4 times and there will be more rules in the future. And upcoming new rule will add another boolean and 2 more calculations.

Is there some nice design pattern that I'm not spotting here that I should be using?

Comment: So many questions...first, is the method in the Insurance class or some other class?

Answer (score 3):

First, lets solve the problem you have today, which is a way to clean up the repetitive calculation code.

To start with, we need to apply the Stratgey pattern to your price calculation be defining the interface of the calculation and moving the different calculation logic code into their new home:

```
// calculation common interface
public interface IPriceCalculation 
{
   public InsurancePrice CalculatePrice(CarData data);   
}

// result from the calculation
public class InsurancePrice
{
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }      
}


// concrete implementations 
public class BrandDealerMonthlyPaymentCalculation : IPriceCalculation
{
   public InsurancePrice CalculatePrice(CarData data)
   {
      // logic to perform calculation of BrandDealer = true, MonthPayment = true

      // just for example...
      return new InsurancePrice() 
      { 
         Description = "Policy price with a Brand dealer and monthly payments",
         Price = 250.25;
      };
   }
}

public class BrandDealerYearlyPaymentCalculation : IPriceCalculation
{
   public InsurancePrice CalculatePrice(CarData data)
   {
      // logic to perform calculation of BrandDealer = true, MonthPayment = false
   }
}

public class NonBrandDealerYearlyCalculation : IPriceCalculation
{
   public InsurancePrice CalculatePrice(CarData data)
   {
      // logic to perform calculation of BrandDealer = false, MonthPayment = false
   }
}

public class NonBrandDealerMonthlyCalculation : IPriceCalculation
{
   public InsurancePrice CalculatePrice(CarData data)
   {
      // logic to perform calculation of BrandDealer = false, MonthPayment = true
   }
}
```

With the calculations defined, you to install them.  Within the class that defines the GetInsurance method (lets call it InsuranceFactory) we will do this in your ctor.  This could be done via another class pushing them in via properties, via config, via DI, whatever, but the ctor is simplest for illustration:

```
public class InsuranceFactory
{
   private List<IPriceCalculation> _priceCalculators = new List<IPriceCalculation>();

   public InsuranceFactory()
   {
      _priceCalculators.Add(new BrandDealerYearlyPaymentCalculation());
      _priceCalculators.Add(new BrandDealerMonthlyPaymentCalculation());
      _priceCalculators.Add(new NonBrandDealerYearlyCalculation());
      _priceCalculators.Add(new NonBrandDealerMonthlyCalculation());
      // easy to add more calculations right here...
   }

}
```

Next we revisit your GetInsurance method in the InsuranceFactory class above:

```
public Insurance GetInsurance(CarData carData) 
{     
   var insurance = new Insurance();      

   // iterate the different pricing models and them to the insurance policy results

   foreach (IPriceCalculation calculator in _priceCalculators)
   {
      insurance.PriceOptions.Add(calculator.CalculatePrice(carData));
   }

   return insurance; 

}
```

Notice how your GetInsurance method no longer needs to change each time you create a new calculation.  Likewise, by storing the results in a list within the insurance object (`insurance.PriceOptions`) your Insurance class does not need to change either.  Your UI code can present all options by iterating that list.  This example is slightly simplified but should get you going.

Now a few words on a possible second problem I can anticipate.  If your calculation subclasses start having additional permutations you are going to have a class explosion.  For example, right now you have 2 factors (Brand and PaySchedule), each with 2 choices, giving you 2 x 2 = 4 classes.  But what if we add CreditScore into it, with 3 choices (Goor, Fair, Poor).  Then you get:

```
GoodCreditBrandDealerYearlyPaymentCalculation
GoodCreditBrandDealerMonthlyPaymentCalculation
GoodCreditNonBrandDealerYearlyCalculation
GoodCreditNonBrandDealerMonthlyCalculation
FairCreditBrandDealerYearlyPaymentCalculation
FairCreditBrandDealerMonthlyPaymentCalculation
FairCreditNonBrandDealerYearlyCalculation
FairCreditNonBrandDealerMonthlyCalculation
PoorCreditBrandDealerYearlyPaymentCalculation
PoorCreditBrandDealerMonthlyPaymentCalculation
PoorCreditNonBrandDealerYearlyCalculation
PoorCreditNonBrandDealerMonthlyCalculation
```

This only gets worse from here.  This is really worth its own question and answer if it comes up, but it is something you should watch for.  If it start to get like this, refactor the Calculation classes.  But what is nice is the code in GetInsurance still doesn't need to change.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is break your calcualtion into smaller components.
You need to find the common code and save it in a map.
Lets say that calc 1 = A * B + C.
and calc 2 = A * C - b

You need to perform A , B ,C only once and save it in hashmap.
now 
calc 2 = hash.getOrAdd(A key) * hash.getOrAdd(C key) - hash.getOrAdd(C key).

If you can't find any comon code, than your out of luck and need to perform all the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that really sticks out is that you create 4 new Car objects each time you calculate. Is that completely necessary? Could you have 4 of those created beforehand (and stored), with the different BrandDealer/MonthlyPayment combinations, then just use them to calculate passing in the appropriate CarData?

Additionally, this might be better achieved using some sort of a calculation factory, which abstracts/hides the different Car objects needed and other calculation details. Consider adding internal methods for each calculation type, so that for new calculations, you just need to add another method instead of modifying one big method. Typically this would be achieved by adding calculation objects instead of methods, but that may be overkill for this particular situation.